# Тире или двоеточие - что когда?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте!

"Двоеточие ставится после предложения, за которым следует одно или несколько предложений, не соединенных с первым посредством cоюзов и заключающих в себе:

а) разъяснение или раскрытие содержания того, о чем говорится в первом предложении.

б) основание, причина того, о чем говорится в первом предложении".

На примере этого предложения:

*Но мы до сих пор у них ничего не купили — во-первых, они нам не могут сейчас ничего поставить, во-вторых, они анонсировали нам стоимость своей продукции примерно на 30% дороже других аналогов.*

Почему здесь стоит тире? Вроде есть разъяснение.

На всякий случай дам полную версию предложения.

*Собеседник в ООО «Искра-Турбогаз» (крупнейший в РФ поставщик газоперекачивающих агрегатов) сообщил „Ъ“, что при создании «Рустурбомаша» предполагалось использование компрессоров на ГПА пермского предприятия: «Но мы до сих пор у них ничего не купили — во-первых, они нам не могут сейчас ничего поставить, во-вторых, они анонсировали нам стоимость своей продукции примерно на 30% дороже других аналогов».*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Двоеточие в БСП применяется для выражения изъяснения, пояснения и следственно-причинных отношений. Это классический вариант.

В то же время во всех трех значениях вместо двоеточия можно использовать тире, но в этом случае меняется интонация и появляются дополнительные оттенки значения. Во-первых, отсутствует предупредительная пауза, характерная для двоеточия. Во-вторых, присоединяемая часть получает оттенок добавочного сообщения. Мы как бы считаем основной мыслью первую часть предложения, а далее присоединяем вторую часть, подчеркивая ее разъяснительный характер.

Comment: В данном предложении возможно и двоеточие, и тире. Если брать полный текст, то я бы поставила тире. В этом случае центр тяжести сообщения приходится на то, что ничего не купили, а причина идет как дополнительное сообщение. Если вы хотите основное внимание уделить именно причине, то надо ставить двоеточие. В этом случае перед разъяснением нужно будет сделать предупредительную паузу.

Comment: После слов "на ГПА пермского предприятия" я бы поставил рядовую точку! Потому что никакого раскрытия намерений об использовании в закавыченной прямой речи уже нет, это пройденный этап, там уже отражено дальнейшее развитие событий с (возможной) перспективой смены поставщика оборудования.

Кстати, слова в болде я бы отсюда удалил: «...во-вторых, они анонсировали **нам** стоимость своей продукции примерно на 30% дороже **других** аналогов».
Кстати-2: что-то непонятен смысл и предлог "на" в словах "предполагалось использование компрессоров на ГПА пермского предприятия".

Comment: Потому, возможно, и поставлено тире в прямой речи, что двоеточие уже есть перед прямой речью. Если перед прямой речью поставить точку, то после слова *купили*, перед *во-первых*, уместно простое двоеточие.

Comment: Предложение кажется некорректным, я бы его изменила примерно так: Собеседник в ООО «Искра-Турбогаз» (крупнейший в РФ поставщик газоперекачивающих агрегатов) сообщил, что при создании «Рустурбомаша» предполагалось использование компрессоров на ГПА пермского предприятия. «Но мы до сих пор у них ничего не купили, –  сказал он в беседе нашим корреспондентом.  –  Во-первых, они нам не могут сейчас ничего поставить, во-вторых, они анонсировали нам стоимость своей продукции примерно на 30% дороже других аналогов».

Answer (score 2):

Вы правы, в этом предложении нужно поставить двоеточие вместо тире: вторая часть БСП указывает на причину того, о чём говорится в первой.